# When and when not to use zero values in one-way ANOVA

Tags: anova, modeling

I have a dataset consisting of 5 pollination treatments to 20 different plants (5 flowers per plant) which contains 25 zero values (aborted flowers). Should I use the zero values or ignore them and run tests with unequal sample sizes. I am leaning toward the former as aborted flowers is a significant outcome to the treatments. In general though, when should zero values be excluded from ANOVA?

Comment: It all depends on the *meaning*, in your experiment, of "zero" and "aborted."  What exactly are you measuring?  How does an outcome become "aborted"? How is that related to what you are trying to learn?

Comment: It means that the flower produced zero seeds. That is why it is informative, I think. The experiment was testing the efficacy of 5 different treatments on fertilization of the flowers. So I am trying to learn which mode is most successful from the plant's perspective.

Comment: This doesn't seem to explain enough about what's going on; a great deal more explanation is needed. I suspect you may not want ordinary one way ANOVA at all. What is your response variable? Number of seeds?

Comment: If zero is just a very unsuccessful outcome, then it would be illogical to exclude these outcomes just for being a low value. If on the other hand e.g. someone accidentally trampled these plants when they were still small (and this was definitely unrelated to the potential outcome, i.e. we are pretty sure it did not happen because they developed more slowly than the other plants and thus were overlooked) so that they never had a chance to develop seeds, this may not say anything about the treatments you studied. In that case there is an argument for excluding such records or imputing outcomes.